# How to play H264 Video file using VideoToolbox.framework in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, iphone, video, ios8, streaming

I want to play a `.H264` video file in `iOS 8` with use of `VideoToolbox.framework` and not with `ffmpeg` library.

I have found few Tutorials + Reference links to understand `VideoToolbox.framework`, but still couldn't find, "how to play `.H264` in `iOS`?".

Few Examples :

- https://github.com/manishganvir/iOS-h264Hw-Toolbox
- https://github.com/McZonk/VideoToolboxPlus

Reference Links :

- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_8/VideoToolbox.html
- https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?include=513#513
- [Decoding H264 VideoToolkit API fails with Error -8971 in VTDecompressionSessionCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039345/decoding-h264-videotoolkit-api-fails-with-error-8971-in-vtdecompressionsessionc)

You can download a test (.H264) video for Testing from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n68v5mty4h0sqog/test2.h264?dl=0).

Comment: "Play H264 Video in iPhone" is still not a question. Its not even a complete sentence.

Comment: How to play .H264 video file in IOS ?
here is sample video. Please check
https://www.dropbox.com/s/n68v5mty4h0sqog/test2.h264?dl=0
I need to play this video in iPhone.

Comment: This question has detailed answer about decoding H.264 with VideoToolbox framework: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525000/how-to-use-videotoolbox-to-decompress-h-264-video-stream.

Answer (score 1):

`VideoToolbox.framework` is not used to display video files on screen but rather for decoding and conversion of video data. Use `AVKit.framework` or `AVFoundation.framework` to play a H264 video instead.

See Apples [documentation of the Media Layer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001067-CH273-SW18):

> The Video Toolbox framework
>   comprises the 64-bit replacement for the QuickTime Image Compression
>   Manager. Video Toolbox provide services for video compression and
>   decompression, and for conversion between raster image formats stored
>   in Core Video pixel buffers.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your trying to decode. If you have a File or valid end point. AVFoundation is what your looking for.

The VideoToolBox is for decoding video manually. Which is used in real-time streaming. For this case you will be required to parse the NAL units from each payload and follow this tutorial:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29525001/2878935

Comment: Wo thats a pretty intense response. Well unlike you i have actually wrote an ios application which can concurrently stream 9 RTSP streams and i use videotoolbox to do video decoding and implement my own frame dropping. So yeah i dont know what i am talking about...

Comment: I am under an NDA for that app. And i am fairly sure i posted a some of the android/ios hacks for h.264 in other posts. Just for you my precious snow flake i will upload my own ios decoder tomorrow to github... You have to be the angriest Christian i have ever talked to btw.

Comment: Maybe, but I never let the sun set on it [Eph 4:26]. To that end, I'm very much looking forward to seeing what you have. It's not that I don't understand how to use Video Toolbox as presented in the various sample code snippets provided online. It is the lack of an end-to-end presentation of a solution using it that leads me to believe that no one but a few knows how to read a video file using a bare-bones file reader like dispatch I/O, decode and otherwise process it into a series of Core Media sample buffers, and display them on-screen using, for example, AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer.

Comment: did you upload anything yet?